# instance of File pointers in c++

Tags: c, file

My actual code is

```
void alter_info(char * fileName){
    system("CLS");
    char * studentName = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)* 30);
    char * subject = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)* 30); int choice;
    printf("1. Add a student to the file\n2. Change a student name\n3. Change a student marks\n4. Delete a student from %s\n0. Goto Root\n", fileName);
    while (1){
        printf(">>Enter option :");
        scanf("%d", &choice);  fflush(stdin);
        switch (choice){
        case 1:{
                   printf(">>Enter student name :");
                   gets(studentName); fflush(stdin);
                   add_student_and_marks(fileName, studentName);
                   break;
        }
        case 2:{
                   printf(">>Enter student name to be changed :");
                   gets(studentName); fflush(stdin);
                   printf(">>Enter new name for %s :", studentName);
                   gets(subject); fflush(stdin);
                   change_student_name(fileName, studentName, subject);
                   break;
        }
        case 3:{
                   printf(">>Enter student whose marks are to be changed :");
                   gets(studentName); fflush(stdin);
                   change_stduent_marks(fileName, studentName);
                   break;
        }
        case 4:{
                   printf(">>Enter student to be removed :");
                   gets(studentName); fflush(stdin);
                   delete_student_data(fileName, studentName);
                   break;
        }
        case 0:{
                   system("cls");
                   printf("1. View student info\n2. Change student details\n3. Show leaderboard\n4. Query region\n0. exit\n");
                   return;
        }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

while accessing the case 2 in switch case i am:

1. creating a temp file
2. Deleting the original file
3. and finally, renaming the temp file to original file name...

I am facing a problem of NULL pointer while accessing it second time.

**Code of `change_student_name` is :**

```
void change_student_name(char * fileName, char * studentnName, char * nameToBeReplaced){
    char * tempName = tempExtension(fileName);
    FILE * fp = fopen(fileName, "r"), *wptr = fopen(tempName, "w+");
    //Skipping subject count and subject names...
    fprintf(wptr, "%s\n", getLine(fp));
    fprintf(wptr, "%s\n", getLine(fp));
    bool correct = false;
    while (1){
        char * temp = getLine(fp);
        if (temp == NULL){
            break;
        }
        if (stringCmp(temp, studentnName)){
            correct = true;
            fprintf(wptr, "%s\n", nameToBeReplaced);
            printf("Successfully replaced %s to %s in <%s>\n", studentnName, nameToBeReplaced, fileName);
        }
        else
            fprintf(wptr, "%s\n", temp);
        fprintf(wptr, "%s\n", getLine(fp));
    }
    if (!correct){
        printf("ERROR :: %s is not in the given file <%s>\n", studentnName, fileName);
    }
    fclose(wptr);
    fclose(fp);
    remove(fileName);
    rename(tempName, fileName);
}
```

`getLine(FILE * fp)` returns an entire line from the file
`getName(FILE * fp)` returns a word till the delimiter(,) or end..

Comment: I don't see much C++ here, more like good old C.

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` - this is undefined behaviour

Comment: Please share the code for `change_student_name`. Otherwise we can only guess what is wrong.

Comment: Don't ever use `gets`, it's dangerous. It has also been deprecated since the C99 standard, and removed completely in the C11 standard.

Comment: And why are you using `malloc` to allocate a fixed-size buffer? What's wrong with arrays (if you're programming C) or `std::string` (if you're really programming in C++)? Also, since you use `malloc` to allocate memory for the strings, but don't call `free` each call to the function will lead to a *memory leak*.

Comment: Ignoring the use of `gets`, the use of `malloc`ed buffers in C++, the undefined behaviour triggered by `fflush(stdin)`, there is not enough information here to help you in any way. We have no problem believing what you think `change_student_name` does, but unless you show us its code we cannot tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: And don't post screenshots of code, *copy and paste* it into your question body instead.

Comment: can you give a bit more information about the "problem of NULL pointer" you are getting ? What do you see (including output, error messages, crashes, etc.) ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is removing the file and renaming the temp_file to original_file in same instance. Solved this by storing it in a buffer and finally storing in the file without creating a new instance for the file.

```
char * writeWordToString(char * main, int * pos, char * word){
    if (word == NULL)
        return main;
    while (*word != '\0'){
        main = (char *)realloc(main, sizeof(char)*(*pos + 1));
        main[(*pos)++] = *word;
        word++;
    }
    return main;
}

void change_student_name(char * fileName, char * studentnName, char * nameToBeReplaced){
    char * buffer = NULL;
    int buffer_end = 0;
    char * tempName = tempExtension(fileName);
    FILE * fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
    //Skipping subject count and subject names...
    buffer = writeWordToString(buffer, &buffer_end, getLine(fp));
    buffer = writeWordToString(buffer, &buffer_end, "\n");
    buffer = writeWordToString(buffer, &buffer_end, getLine(fp));
    buffer = writeWordToString(buffer, &buffer_end, "\n");
    bool correct = false;
    while (1){
        char * temp = getLine(fp);
        if (temp == NULL){
            break;
        }
        if (stringCmp(temp, studentnName)){
            correct = true;
            buffer = writeWordToString(buffer, &buffer_end, nameToBeReplaced);
            buffer = writeWordToString(buffer, &buffer_end, "\n");
            printf("Successfully replaced %s to %s in <%s>\n", studentnName, nameToBeReplaced, fileName);
        }
        else{
            buffer = writeWordToString(buffer, &buffer_end, temp);
            buffer = writeWordToString(buffer, &buffer_end, "\n");
        }
        buffer = writeWordToString(buffer, &buffer_end, getLine(fp));
        buffer = writeWordToString(buffer, &buffer_end, "\n");
    }
    if (!correct){
        printf("ERROR :: %s is not in the given file <%s>\n", studentnName, fileName);
        free(buffer);
        return;
    }
    char * buff_temp = buffer;
    FILE *wptr = fopen(fileName, "w");
    buffer[buffer_end] = '\0';
    while (*buffer != '\0'){
        fputc((int)*buffer, wptr);
        buffer++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(wptr);
    free(buff_temp);
    return;
}
```